# Java: Creating a car game application

Tags: java

This is a practice question for a test I'll be taking next week. However, I am only able to get to 4.2C before I am clueless. We have never even created a constructor for an array in class and the rest of it I have no idea how to do. Any help on this?

The carGame class should have one constructor, which will initialize “carList” for all 5 elements. When you do initialization, each car in this carList, must have a unique carId (0-4), unique carName (For example John’s Mustang), and unique car Model picked from the carModelList.

I'm not sure how to get the constructor working nor do I know how to make it a unique carId

Below is what I currently have:

```
public class car {

    public int carId;
    public String carName;
    public int racePosition;
    public String carModel;

    //constructor with 3 parameters
    public car(int carId, String carName, String carModel) {
        this.carId = carId;
        this.carName = carName;
        this.carModel = carModel;
    }

    public void Display()
    {
        System.out.println(carName + " is ranked " + racePosition + ". Model is " + carModel);
    }

}


public class carGame {

    public static String[] carModelList = {"Mustang", "Nissan_370Z", "BMW_M3", "Audi_R8", "Porsche_911"};
    private car[] carList = new car[5];

    public carGame(String[] carList) {


    }

    public void Display(){


    }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

You dont need carsList passed in constructor. You could do something like:

```
String carNames[] = {"Name1", "Name2" ...};//pre define car name
public carGame() {
    for (int i =0; i<carList.length; i++) {
         carList[i] = new Car(i + 1, carNames[i], carModelList[i]);//you get unique car id every time from loop index
    }
}
```

Comment: But it must also have a carId. I tried to add carId into what you showed but it says it cant be referenced from a static context.

Comment: What can't be referenced frm static context? Can you paste your updated code in question?